# Laravel /Laravel Collective Operaciones Mátematicas

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Busque ejemplos y no encontre nada, pero habria alguna manera de realizar operaciones matemáticas entre los datos obtenidos de los input?

Es decir:

Nº de Productos que compro:

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('cantidad', 'Cantidad') !!}
     {!! Form::text('cantidad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Cantidad obtenida', 'required']) !!}
</div>
```

Por el precio:

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('total', 'Total de la Factura') !!}
     {!! Form::text('total', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total' , 'required']) !!}
</div>
```

Obtener el resultado en un tercer campo que es escriba solo:

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('precio_total', 'Precio Total') !!}
     {!! Form::text('precio_total', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio Total' , 'required']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Pero quieres que lo calcule de forma dinámica en el lado del cliente? quieres que mediante peticiones ajax se calcule de forma dinámica en el lado del servidor? O quieres que se calcule en el servidor y al cargar la pagina simplemente se muestre?

Comment: Pues diria yo que que lo suyo sería de forma dinamica según se vayan implementando los numeros en el input, es decir según el cliente vaya escribiendo que se vayan realizando dihcas operaciones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo los ids para los elementos que si indican en el código y teniendo en cuenta que faltaria que hicieses validaciones de los datos de entrada en los listeners, el esqueleto del código que necesitas es el siguiente.

```
function multiplicar(op1, op2){
    //Suponiendo que el campo de texto donde quieres el resultado tiene el id "resultado"
    document.getElementById("resultado").setAttribute("value", op1 * op2);
}

//suponiendo el id para el input de la cantidad "cantidad"
document.getElementById("cantidad").addEventListener("change", function(){
    multiplicar(document.getElementById("cantidad").value, document.getElementById("precio").value);
});

//suponiendo el id para el input de la precio "precio"
document.getElementById("precio").addEventListener("change", function(){
    multiplicar(document.getElementById("cantidad").value, document.getElementById("precio").value);
});
```

El código debería ir añadido en un fragmento `<script></script>` de tu pagina web;

Comment: No va a funcionar por el código de `Laravel Collective`pero te djeo un ejemplo de como lo intente pero no me funciona https://jsfiddle.net/thnexwnv/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thnexwnv/2/ Edito por que encontre algun fallo aun que sigue sin funcionar